# Is there any performance benefit to creating an index mapping for Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I was wondering for people who have used Elasticsearch at scale if there is a performance benefit while searching if I create an index mapping and then put documents in it compared to not creating a mapping and just directly putting documents in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is usually *preferable* to create the explicit mapping for an index, where possible.

For a search case, this is crucial in order to index data with the analysis chains needed to service the search strategy.

For a log use case, it may not be possible to know what the explicit mapping should be for log records that will be ingested, as there may be dynamic fields in the data that is not known ahead of time. [Dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html) can help here, as can adopting a unified logging structure like [Elastic Common Schema (ECS)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/ecs/master/ecs-reference.html), either converting data to ECS format whilst logging, or converting whilst ingesting into Elasticsearch with [ingest pipelines](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/ingest.html)

Comment: Well, tbh indexing is easy but my use case would require me to add new fields to the mapping every few months or so for some time. I didn't find a good resource on doing that in Python or otherwise. I am not sure if that involves re-indexing the entire thing or what.

Comment: Actually didn't look hard enough. There is some good doc on this https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v7.12.1/api.html#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.put_mapping

Comment: Just bear in mind that updating mappings is usually only additive, i.e. adding new fields, but not changing existing fields

Comment: Yep thats mostly the case for now. Maybe there is going to be a case where I need to change the data type of old fields and I think that is where re-index comes in I think. I have to just create a new mapping with same field names but potentially different data types and use reindex to transfer all data. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Okay so I actually ended up benchmarking and I did not see any performance benefit while searching. I guess the benefit is for tricky fields we can specify what we want. But hypothetically if it were just one field TEXT manual mapping vs dynamic mapping has no performance benefits.

Comment: By default, all text fields will be analysed with the standard analyzer. Whilst the standard analyzer is a decent default, it may be insufficient for specific search cases, for example, searching an Asian language like Korean or Japanese, or legal or medical search use cases. There are two performance measures one might be interested in too- indexing latency and throughput, and searching latency and throughput. Choice of analysis may affect both in different ways

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is always better to use explicit mapping before putting the documents rather than depending on the dynamic mapping. If at all you are dependent on the dynamic mapping you may not be able to visualize on few data types like text. And also when you maintain mapping your index will always have the same kind of data. Please refer to this blog:

[https://qbox.io/blog/maximize-guide-elasticsearch-indexing-performance-part-1/][1]